# Are all posts reviewed by any particular set of people to maintain the quality of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Suppose somebody has accepted the wrong answer, or few people up-vote a wrong answer. Then it obviously lowers the quality of Stack Overflow. Is there any assigned set of people on Stack Overflow who ensure that no incorrect post is left on Stack Overflow?

I know there is an option to flag the post to get a moderator's attention, but what option does Stack Overflow have when nobody flags it?

Comment: [If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest)

Comment: How do you know an answer is wrong?

Comment: @gnat, too zen for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that particular set of people is each and every user of the site. We vote posts up when we find them to be good or correct, and we vote them down if they are wrong, bad or perhaps even harmful. Truly off-topic content can even get deleted.

That system is not perfect. But it works reasonably well.

Do however not use flags for wrong answers. That is what downvotes are for. Moderators are not in the business of judging the correctness of answers. Such flags will be rejected.

Answer (score 4):

You can always vote the wrong answers down (if you have enough rep), and then leave a comment stating that the answer is wrong and why it is wrong so that the poster (and other users) can judge and vote correspondingly, or reply to your comment with counter arguments. This is how the current system works.

If you have an answer, you can (and should) also post it. If your answer is correct, it will (eventually) get upvoted and sort of "replace" the wrong answer.